# wpa_supplicant errors in syslog after upgrade to Stretch

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, update, wpa

I just upgraded a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B from Jessie to Stretch, and everything (including WiFi) seems to be working OK, but one thing has me worried: Whenever I reboot, `sudo journalctl` contains the following errors:

```
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
                                                            You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
                                                            left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
                                                            to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

I think systemd is starting wpa_supplicant and then dhcpcd-run-hooks is trying to start it again. I say this because of the output from `grep -i wpa /var/log/syslog`:

```
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[323]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 dhcpcd[329]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 dhcpcd-run-hooks[389]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
May 28 17:41:48 RasSpy3 wpa_supplicant[445]: Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.#012You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was#012left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need#012to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

Anyone know what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: You say you "upgraded a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B from Jessie to Stretch" - How? This CAN be done, but is not officially supported. A fresh install is the recommended method. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways Your linked article provided the solution: "If you are running a recent Raspbian /etc/network/interfaces should be as below." I removed a bunch of settings from that file that were not included in your example, and the errors went away. Feel free to post that as the answer to this question if you want some shiny internet points.

Comment: I am not a points hound, and an Answer would probably be converted to a Comment. There are quite a few other differences between Jessie and Stretch. The Foundation does not provide the upgrade between versions which other distos do, so it has to be done manually. Even applying my Jessie install script to Stretch was quite an effort. Debian Buster is imminent, and Raspbian Buster is expected in the next few months, so probably not worth the effort in Stretch.